# Angular Formly: TemplateUrl validation

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

My website has several forms where name related info is collected (first, last, suffix, etc). Instead of adding/formatting these fields on each controller on the various pages, I decided to create a simple html file that has these fields created. This html file simply contains 4 text inputs.

The plan was to use this html file as a template and thus easily be able to incorporate the same name related fields in multiple forms very quickly.

I created a JSBin: http://jsbin.com/nenepuyalu/1/edit?html,js,output

In this example, I am not including my various wrappers or validation logic (too much of a pain).  That said, you can see where I create a new type `nameInputGroup`.  This type is a templateUrl pointing towards `input-group-name.html` which has two text inputs.

I am having issues with making these two inputs validate.  Since they are not added directly to the `fields` array I am not sure how I flag the fields to have the `required` or `min/max` validation requirements.

Any suggestions?  Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Anyone have an idea or two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your use-case correctly, you simply want to be able to not duplicate yourself in the several places that you have the same series of fields. There are several ways to do this. Here's what I would recommend: http://kentcdodds.jsbin.com/mokeza/edit?html,js,output

Basically, you place your configuration in a separate file, then you `concat` those fields with the extra fields you want (you can chain `concat` calls).

Comment: It is a mixture of not wanting to duplicate myself but also add fields to the form via referencing an html file.  My work has a rather annoyingly complex CDN.  Instead of trying to force formly to comply with the craziness that is our CDN, I wanted to just reference an html file where all of the correct `div`s have already been applied.  If you look at my example, `input-group-name.html` is the file I am referencing.  Imagine that this file has far more `div` elements on it.  How can I make the fields within this file (first/middle) be required or pass min/max validation?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm pretty confused by what you're really going for then... what do you mean by "all the correct `div`s have already been applied" ? Something that's noteable is that angular-formly does support multiple `ng-model` elements in a single template, but I would strongly advise against this because it just makes things more complex for you. What about my solution is wrong?

Comment: I totally understand why this is confusing, lol.  Take a look at this: http://jsbin.com/hedofixeya/edit?html,js,output   .  It you look at the `input-group-name2.html` html file you will see the multiple layers of `div`s that our CDN requires.  I was having trouble getting the divs to wrap around the correct fields.  Nothing about your solution is wrong other than the fact that (like I said), I was having trouble getting the divs to wrap around their correct input fields.

Comment: "multiple layers of `div`s that our CDN requires" o_O?? Your CDN has requirements about the contents of your template??? That makes 0 sense to me... Anyway, have you looked into `wrappers`? That might be a solution for you. As I said, I seriously recommend against multiple `ng-model`s in a single template. If you need a very specific HTML structure for some weird reason, then perhaps formly is the wrong solution for you.

Comment: haha, preaching to the choir about our CDN.  I have played around with wrappers.  They work for most things.  But in that example, the wrapper has issues with the `form__input-group` class that goes around the entire group of textboxes.  Any suggestions with that?

Comment: You could potentially specify a `class` on the `formly-form` element of `form__input-group` and use the `className` on the fields: http://jsbin.com/mokeza/edit?html,js,output would that satisfy your CDN?

Comment: Unfortunately, the class has to be on a div surrounding the input or else the class does not get applied correctly.  My team and I dog on this CDN every time it screws us over like this.

Comment: Are you sure it's the CDN and not just your CSS styles? What happens when you CDN doesn't get what it requires? This is extremely odd (non-CDN-like) behavior...

Comment: If the correct classes are applied to the right divs then nothing is aligned or presented to the user correctly.

Comment: That sounds like a CSS problem, not a CDN problem? Can you not alter the CSS to account for this change in structure?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that you responded.  I'm looking into this idea, however, the CSS to our website is within our CDN.  Which is, of course, untouchable by the devs to ensure no one jacks it up.  Yay for me!  I may just make this work by ignoring the CDN and call it a day.  This is wasting my time at this point :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to get something working for me.  Our CDN is so tough to work with because it does so many non-CDN like stuff...